# Could not get unknown property for task in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have the following Gradle Task:

```
  task makeZipDependencies << {
        allDeps = (configurations.runtime + configurations.archives.allArtifacts.files).findAll {
            !(it.name =~ /clover/)
        }                                                                              .unique()
        if ("myApp".equals(project.name)) {
            rootProject.childProjectsRecursive.each {

                try {
                    databaseSqlFileDeps.put(it.name, it.configurations["mySQLFiles"].files)
                } catch (UnknownConfigurationException e) {

                }
            }
        }
```

This was not causing an error previously when I was running my project with java 7 and gradle 1.7.

However, I have moved to Java 8 and gradle 3.4.1 and now I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task "makeZipDependencies", could not get unknown property:childProjectsRecursive for root Project myApp of type org.gradle.api.project"
```

What changes do I need to make to my task to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle's API has changed a lot between version 1.x (you indicated `1.7`) and 3x (latest release as of today is `3.4.1`).

I think what you need is to query the value of the `subprojects` property https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:subprojects

```
rootProject.subprojects.each { ... }
```

Unfortunately there's no single document where you may find all the changes between version 1.x and 3.x. My recommendation is to update build version whenever possible to minimize migration impact. Be always in the lookout of behavior/binary incompatibilities when switching between major release versions.